# For a different version of postgresql, How can i invoke pg_config

Tags: postgresql

For a different version of Postgresql, How can i invoke pg_config?
I have pg15.1 and pg14.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For individual versions you should use the full Path to the Binary

```
> find /usr/lib/postgresql/*/bin/pg_config    
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_config
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_config
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_config
```